# BeautifulSoup returns [ ] when string is present

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a web page and it worked pretty good except a part where re.compile() returns empty [] while the text passed to it is present. Here is my scrape code

```
dob = soup.find(text = re.compile('Date of Birth')).findNext('td').text
print(dob)

father_name = soup.find(text = re.compile("Father's Name")).findNext('td').text
print(father_name)

mob_no_parent = soup.find(text = re.compile("Mobile Number")).findNext('td').text
print(mob_no_parent)

mob_no_student = soup.findAll(text = re.compile("Mobile Number(Student)"))
print(mob_no_student)

email = soup.find(text = re.compile("E - Mail Address")).findNext('td').text
print(email)

p_address = soup.find(text = re.compile("PermanentAddress")).findNext('td').text
print(p_address)
```

The above code works fine on every text except

```
mob_no_student = soup.findAll(text = re.compile("Mobile Number(Student)"))
print(mob_no_student)
```

The above one returns []

Here is my html code

```
<td align="left" width="50%" class="inner_padding_even">&nbsp;&nbsp;Registration No </td>
<td align="left" width="50%" class="inner_padding_even">CPT0000</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" width="50%" class="inner_padding_odd">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name of Candidate</td>
<td align="left" width="50%" class="inner_padding_odd"><font face=arial size=2>KKKKKKK B.</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" class="inner_padding_even">&nbsp;&nbsp;Date of Birth</td>
<td align="left" class="inner_padding_even">16.11.1900</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" class="inner_padding_even">&nbsp;&nbsp;Father's Name</td>
<td align="left" class="inner_padding_even">BBBBBBBB.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" class="inner_padding_even">&nbsp;&nbsp;Mobile    Number</font>(Parent)</td>
<td align="left" class="inner_padding_even">99999999999</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" class="inner_padding_odd">&nbsp;&nbsp;Mobile Number(Student)</td>
<td align="left" class="inner_padding_odd">9999999999</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" class="inner_padding_even">&nbsp;&nbsp;E - Mail Address</td>
<td align="left" class="inner_padding_even">keyansgm@gmail.com</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left" class="inner_padding_even">&nbsp;Permanent Address</td>
<td width="50%" align="left" class="inner_padding_even">Blah blah</td>
</tr>
```

What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regex, you need to escape brackets, If not it will refer to a group

Try this

```
mob_no_student = soup.findAll(text = re.compile("Mobile Number\(Student\)"))
```

Comment: Great answer... except they are parenthesis not brackets. Brackets need to be escaped too of course, but these are parenthensis.